# I need to replace an in wall doggie door that came out of the wall on the outside… can I use the same doggie door to replace it?

Tags: repair, walls

My 2yr old doggie door came out of the wall on the outside. I purchased a new one to install but I’m wondering if I can install it using the same template or will it come out because the holes for the screws were previously used? I’m new at this, having someone installing the first one and I can’t hire anyone this time due to finances.

Comment: Can you add to your question pictures of the new door and the hole in the wall from both sides?

Answer (score 1):

The common way to reuse holes that do not hold screws as well, is to use toothpicks and wood glue.

Put wood glue on the toothpicks and stuff them into the screw holes.

Use something sharp to cut the toothpicks even with the surface of the door.

Install the new doggie door with the same template, if it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If it came out of the wall, chances are the holes were inlarged or the screws were stripped. If you are replacing the door with exactly the same type, try mounting it with the new screws in the same holes. If it's secure, you're done. If the screws don't hold. shove some toothpicks in the holes and re screw.